# Shifting Denominator in a Finite Alternating Series

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, number-theory, estimation

Suppose I have the following finite alternating series:

$ \sum\limits_{k=1}^{n} (-1)^k \frac{a_k}{k} = 0$

Where $a_k > 0$ Can anything be said about the bounds of the series with a shifted denominator?:

$\sum\limits_{k=1}^{n} (-1)^k \frac{a_k}{k+1}$

Any help or pointers would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: No, because if $a_k$ satisfies $\sum_{k=1}^n (-1)^k \frac{a_k}{k} = 0$, then so does the sequence $b_k = ca_k$ for any $c \in \mathbb R$. However, if $\sum_{k=1}^n (-1)^k \frac{a_k}{k+1} = K\neq 0$, (such sequences $a_k$ exist by a linear algebraic argument) then  $\sum_{k=1}^n (-1)^k \frac{b_k}{k+1} = cK\neq 0$, and because $c$ canbe anything, $cK$ can be anything as well, so you can't say anything about the latter sum.